# which feature in java 1.7 paved the way for lambda expression in 1.8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-7

I want to understand the feature in java 1.7 which paved the way for lambda expression in Java 1.8. Anonymous function is legacy feature of Java , it exist even before Java 1.7.

```
Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
    int compare(String s, String s2) { ... }
};
```

Comment: The language feature “lambda expressions” did not require any of the previous work, though it works much better with Generics and enhanced type inference on the language level. On the JVM level, there’s indeed a [feature called “anonymous classes”](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/anonymous-classes-in-the-vm), which must not be confused with the Java language feature of the same name, and the `invokedynamic` instruction, both introduced in Java 7, which together helped to implement lambda expressions efficiently. But they were not strictly required for adding lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

They are called anonymous classes, not anonymous functions.  To find out more about them, your "first stop" should be the Oracle Java Tutorial:

- [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Anonymous classes have existed since Java 1.1.  However, it is a stretch to call them "legacy".  There are significant differences between anonymous classes and lambdas.  For example, an anonymous class may implement multiple methods, and may extend an existing class.  By contrast, the innate functionality of a lambda is limited to the code in the lambda itself.